# linux red hat enterprise linux

Tags: linux, java-home

I installed jdk1.6.0_16 on enterprise linux 4 and I also set teh JAVA_HOME in my ~/.bash_profile

echo $JAVA_HOME correctly shows the new path of the java file

export JAVA_HOME=/jdk16/jdk1.6.0_16/bin/java

The bin directory is also int he path

However when I do java -version I still see java version "1.4.2"

How do I see newly installed jdk verion when i issue java -version command

Answer (score 2):

```
whereis java
```

Type that in, and it will show you the locations java is kept.

[Here is a page about it](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_whereis.htm)

Or execute the java binary directly using: `/jdk16/jdk1.6.0_16/bin/java -version`

Comment: @ttommy851, it would be polite for you to start awarding some answers... thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what PostMan said, you should also modify your PATH envvar in the following way:

```
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME:$PATH
```

put this in your bash_profile.  This will guarantee you pick up the 1.60 jdk.  Also your JAVA_HOME should probably be;

```
JAVA_HOME=/jdk16/jdk1.6.0_16/bin
```

that is you shouldn't put the path to the actual java executable in JAVA_HOME.  It should point to the java installs bin directory.

Answer (score 1):

Executing

```
which java
```

will tell you which jvm's executable you're running when you just run java -version.

With multiple JVMs installed, it's best to fully specify the path or set your PATH environment variable appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ vi ~/.bash_profile
```

--> Add

```
export JAVA_HOME=<path to java jdk>
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME:$PATH
```

--> write/save

```
Esc + : + w
```

--> quit editor

```
Esc + : + q
```